# do "const" declarations help the compiler (GCC) produce faster code?

Tags: c++, c, performance, gcc, g++

Do `const` declarations help the compiler (GCC) produce faster code or are they only useful for readability and correctness?

Zed Shaw has argued that `const` is useless or is overused in C/C++:

> Next is all the bizarre fascination with const.  For some odd reason
>   C++ loves to make you slap const on every part of a declaration, and
>   yet I get the same end result as C: a function is called. (...)

(From: http://librelist.com/browser//mongrel2/2010/7/15/c-verses-c++/#770d94bcfc6ddf1d8510199996b607dd )

Comment: Const, like many other C++ keywords is overloaded. When used for access control in passing a pointer/reference the optimizer cannot infer whether or not the underlying data may change due to aliasing. When used to initialize external/static constant data however the compiler does know that the variable may never change. One crucial case is embedded systems where large constant arrays may be placed directly into ROM rather than wasting precious RAM.

Comment: Honestly, his rant seems very much based on the fact he doesn't really know what he's doing in C++ (and doesn't care to).

Comment: Zed's comment about const is rather dumb.  C++ doesn't make you do anything.  The language doesn't make you type const anywhere.  You can write an entire program without it.  Other programmers might make dumb design decisions or use const and const_cast incorrectly, but there is nothing wrong with the language itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `const` modifier on method, references and pointers can't be used to optimize code for a couple of reasons.  The primary one is that `const` modifier, in those contexts, doesn't make any guarantees about the underlying data not changing, it just makes it harder to modify it.  Here is a classic example

```
void M(const C& p1, C& p2) { 
  cout << p1.field << endl;
  p2.Mutate();
  cout << p1.field<< endl;
}
```

In this case it's very possible that `p1.field` is modified in this code.  The most obvious case is that `p1` and `p2` refer to the same value.

```
C local;
M(local, local);
```

Hence there is no real optimization the compiler can do here.  The `const` parameter is equally as dangerous as the non-const one.

The other reason why it can't really optimize is that anyone can cheat in C++ with `const_cast`.

```
class C { 
public:
  int field;

  int GetField() const { 
    C* pEvil = const_cast<C*>(this);
    pEvil->field++;
    return field;
  }
};
```

So even if you are dealing with a single `const` reference the values are still free to change under the hood.

Comment: I disagree with your arguments. While it is true that the compiler will have a hard time in trying to enforce your correct usage of `const` on member functions, `const` still serves as a hint to the compiler that you promise that the function does not alter the object's state. @KonradRudolph's answer is correct: When you declare a function `const` the compiler can assume that it actually is `const` and may thus avoid copying an object which is meant to be immutable.

Comment: The inverse of "In general" is quite different from "Never, It is Impossible"

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Here’s one concrete example. `const` makes it possible to pass arguments by `const&` rather than by value (which might require a costly copy). It’s important to realise that the alternative to pass-by-`const&` is *not* pass-by-`&` because the latter doesn’t allow temporaries to be bound. So, for instance, this code:

```
auto result = foo{1} + foo{2} + foo{3};
```

may call `foo operator +(foo const&, foo const&)` but it may *not* call `foo operator +(foo&, foo&)`.

That way, `const` helps avoid copies.

But generally, `const` is a tool to ensure *correctness*, not to to aid optimisations.

Either way, Zed Shaw has no idea what he’s talking about. The rest of his rant is similarly misinformed, by the way.

Answer (score 7):

No, `const` does not help the compiler make faster code. `Const` is for const-correctness, not optimizations.

The C++ standard says that `const` items can't be modified, but *also* says that `const_cast` should remove the `const` modifier from an object and make it writable (unless it's located in actually read-only memory, in which case the behavior is undefined); as such `const` cannot mean, in general, that the target variable will not change.

I can only think of these two very narrow scenarios where having `const` produces faster code than not having it:

- the variable is global with internal linkage (`static`) and is passed by reference or pointer to a function defined in a different translation unit (different file). In this case, the compiler cannot elide reads to it if it is not marked `const`;
- the variable is global with external linkage (`extern`). Reads to a `const extern` can be elided *inside the file that defines it* (but nowhere else).

When `const` is applied to a global variable, the compiler is allowed to assume that the value will never change because it will place it in read-only memory, and this means undefined behavior if the program attempts to modify it, and compiler authors *love* to rely on the threat of undefined behavior to make code faster.

Note that both scenarios apply **only** to global variables, which probably make for a very minor portion of the variables in your program. To its merit, however, `const` implies `static` at the global level in C++ (this is not the case in C).

Someone above said that using `const` can make code faster because it's possible to use `const` references. I would argue here that what make the code faster is the use of a reference, not the use of `const`.

That said, I still believe `const` is a very sharp knife with which you can't cut yourself and I would advise that you use it whenever it's appropriate, but don't do it for performance reasons.

Comment: `const_cast` cannot always be applied. `const` declarations *can* guarantee that an object doesn’t change, and thus simplify program flow analysis and elide memory reads.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, no matter if the variable is marked `const` or not, the compiler will be able to elide memory reads if it sees that the variable is never written to. In this case, `const` helps because it implies static linkage by default, and as such `const` variables have their scope limited just like if they had the `static` modifier. A non-const static variable that never changes will benefit from the same optimizations.

Comment: But sometimes the compiler *doesn’t* see this – when the (`const`-declared) variable is passed to a function (via `const&`) outside its translation unit. Here, the only way for the compiler to prove that the variable isn’t modified is to rely on its `const`-ness.

Comment: In which case it can't do read elision, because it needs to pass the value.

Comment: It can elide *subsequent* reads (= after the function call).

Comment: Remember 1 single use-case out of billions of lines of code is sufficient to make a statement true. "const" *can* make code faster and/or smaller; wether it will do so in your case does not matter.

Also with most situations, understanding the code by the human reader, perhaps decades later, overrides performance, provided the code is sufficiently performant to meet the performance specification.

Comment: Casting away const from an object that was defined const is *always* undefined behavior, regardless of it happens to be placed in read-only memory.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, const can (not guaranteed) help the compiler produce faster/more correct code. More so than not, they're just a modifier on data that you express to both the compiler and to other people that read your code that some data is not supposed to change. This helps the type system help you write more correct software.

More important than optimizations, they just prevent your own code and people using your code from writing to data you assume to be invariant.

Comment: Disagree with the first word of this response, which is the only part that OP appears confused about.  Can you describe any example the answer "yes" is actually true?  (Edit: never mind, see Konrad Rudolph's response, although honestly this is probably not what OP (or anyone else) had in mind.)

Comment: @Andrey: Global/static initialized constant data is ROMable. This is taken advantage of by most embedded (von Neumann) compilers to save RAM. The same is true to a less extent on regular modern desktop systems where the such data may be shared between multiple running instances of software.